# Randomly getting JDBCConnectionException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0

In my webapp, I'm frequently getting below exception

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter: SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
        14 Sep 2013 12:19:10,927 [ERROR] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter: IO Error: Connection reset
        14 Sep 2013 12:19:10,927 [ERROR]  could not load an entity: [EntityName]
    nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not load an entity: [EntityName]
```

...

```
14 Sep 2013 12:19:10,930 [WARN]  (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0) com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils: Statement close FAILED.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:5389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.closeOrCache(OracleStatement.java:1578)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:1563)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.close(OracleStatementWrapper.java:94)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.close(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:80)
    at com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:41)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.synchronousDestroyStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:413)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.closeAll(GooGooStatementCache.java:351)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeAllCachedStatements(NewPooledConnection.java:673)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:543)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:470)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

I have tried changing C3P0 configuration but it is not helping

Here is my current configuration:

```
checkoutTimeout     10000   
idleConnectionTestPeriod        0
initialPoolSize     10  
maxIdleTime     28800   
maxPoolSize     20  
minPoolSize     8   
numHelperThreads        5
testConnectionOnCheckin     true
```

Relevant Code:
It is a simple call to HibernateTemplate's get method

```
Object result = getHibernateTemplate().get(entityClass, id);
return (T) result;
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code ?

Comment: It is a simple call to getting object by id (I have updated my question). Also note that, the same call works most of the time. The failure rate is around 1 in 4 calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

though it sounds like you've tried a bunch, if you are using testConnectionOnCheckin, you should combine that with a short, non-zero idleConnectionTestPeriod. for performance, you should also set a preferredTestQuery.

the simplest way to check whether unreliable Connection testing is your issue is to switch from testConnectionOnCheckin to testConnectionOnCheckout (and add a preferredTestQuery to minimize the performance impact). if that resolves your problem, then you know that what you need is good Connection testing, and you can switch back and play around with the length of idleConnectionTestPeriod. if testConnectionOnCheckout doesn't resolve the problem, then its unlikely to be a Connection testing issue. testConnectionOnCheckout is a very reliable setting.

see

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0-0.9.5-pre4/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0-0.9.5-pre4/#configuring_connection_testing